Before Update Insert flow error
We created a flow to block an Opportunity from being saved when its Stage is changed to "Won" and it has OpportunityLineitems that are equal to other OLI from Opportunities related to the same account. The flow is working correctly but there is another flow that when a Quote's Stage is changed to "Accepted by Client" it updates its related Opportunity to "Won".
The automation is crashing as the first flow is returning an exception. The Quote's flow was an After Update Insert so I changed it to a Before Insert and implemented the same logic as in the Opportunity flow (not possible to use a subflow in before insert to avoid copying the logic in both flows).
After implmementing the logic the flow should be working correctlty as I have set the conditions to avoid the update of the Quote for the given conditions but it's still returning  an exception. I checked the debug to see where it is crashing and it seems that is executing both paths of a decision element. If anyone has dealt with a similar issue it would be really useful to know how to solve it.
Thanks for your help.

